# HTML5 "Lower Lights" dynamic text and incorrect mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, mouseover

I'm working on a webpage that has a "Lower Lights" function but the code I have now has a few problems.

The first problem is that for some reason instead of the normal mouse pointer "arrow" it changes to the text select "I" when over the element and its confusing because the user doesn't know its clickable. I've tried changing the tags around it but nothing seems to help.

My second problem is I can't get the text to Dynamically change AND still function. I need it to cycle through "Light: High" > "Light: Medium" > "Light: Low" but with the script I'm using now that seems impossible.

Here is the code that I'm using. Hopefully someone can point out what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction.

Notes: The goal of this was to be as simple and light weight HTML5 as possible. If there is an easier, less code, more light weight, option please let me know. Also I'm not opposed to using jQuery if it makes things more simple but I'm completely lost on that front.

If anymore information is needed please let me know.

```
<html>
        <!-- This script handles the "Lower Lights-->
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#the_lights").fadeTo(1,0);
                        $("#turnoff").click(function () {
                            $("#the_lights").css({'display' : 'block'});
                            $("#the_lights").fadeTo("slow",1);
                        });
                        $("#soft").click(function () {
                            document.getElementById("the_lights").style.display="block";
                            $("#the_lights").fadeTo("slow",0.8);
                        });
                        $("#turnon").click(function () {
                            document.getElementById("the_lights").style.display="block";
                            $("#the_lights").fadeTo("slow",0);
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <style>
                    #the_lights{
                    background-color:#000;
                    height:100%;
                    width:100%;
                    position:absolute;
                    top:0;
                    left:0;
                    display:none;
                    }
                    #standout{
                    padding:5px;
                    background-color:black;
                    margin-left:auto;
                    margin-right:auto;
                    position:relative;
                    z-index:1000;
                    }
                </style>

    <div id ="standout">
    <font color="white">
     <div id = "turnoff">Lights: Low</div>
     <div id = "soft">Lights: Medium</div>
     <div id = "turnon">Lights: High</div>
    </font>
    </div>
    <div id="the_lights"></div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? Your `divs` are not links so you need to use the CSS `cursor` property. `cursor:pointer` so that it *appears* `clickable`. Start out with the first `div` visible and the other 2 `hidden` with the `hidden` CSS class created. I assigned the div id's as numbers. If you actually want `divs` to use to cycle with, then the code below should work.

example here **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gE8VZ/)**

**The jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#the_lights").fadeTo(1,0);

    $(document).on("click","div.lights",function () {
            var divId = $(this).attr("id");
            $(this).hide(); 
            $("#" + divId).show();
            $("#the_lights").css({'display' : 'block'});
        if(divId == 1){       
            $("#2").show();
            $("#1").hide();
            $("#the_lights").fadeTo("slow",0.8);
        }else if(divId == 2){
            $("#2").hide();
            $("#3").show();
            $("#the_lights").fadeTo("slow",1);
        }else if(divId == 3){
            $("#3").hide();
            $("#1").show();
            $("#the_lights").fadeTo("slow",0);
        }    

    });
});
```

**The CSS**

```
#the_lights{
    background-color:#000;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#standout{
    padding:5px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1000;
}

.lights{
    cursor:pointer;   
} 

.hidden{
  display:none;   
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<div id ="standout">
<font color="white">
  <div class='lights' id = "1">Lights: High</div> 
  <div class='lights hidden' id = "2">Lights: Medium</div>  
 <div  class='lights hidden' id = "3">Lights: Low</div>
</font>
</div>
<div id="the_lights"></div>
```

**The fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/gE8VZ/

Answer (score 1):

First for the UI you can change the mouse pointer using CSS `cursor` property: `cursor:pointer;` to let the user know it's clickable. Then you can also set an indicator to the current active *lights* by adding a `class` to change the styling.

You also don't need to set the `display` property everytime, `"#the_lights"` is a `<div>` element so it has a default `block` display. And trim down your code to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lights = $("#the_lights");
    lights.fadeTo(1, 0);

    $('#standout div').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        if($(this).is('#turnoff')){
            lights.fadeTo("slow", 1);
        }else if($(this).is('#soft')){
            lights.fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
        }else if($(this).is('#turnon')){
            lights.fadeTo("slow", 0);
        }
    });

});
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/umB6x/1/).

I'm not quite sure what you mean by: *I need it to cycle through "Light: High" > "Light: Medium" > "Light: Low"* but I think a `<select>` element is a good way to do this. See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/umB6x/2/).